# How to insert 100G integers into a vector on a 32-bit machine?

Tags: c++, iterator, containers, standards, allocator

Say I have 100G integer numbers and want to insert them into `vector<int>` on a 32-bit machine, is it possible?

If I use a custom `allocator` to manage the storage strategy, how to guarantee the following operations are always valid:

```
vector<int> coll;
coll.insert(100G integers);
memcpy(coll.begin() + (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 8), "Hello", 5);
```

Note that the C++ standard requires the objects stored in a `vector` must be consecutive. `coll.begin() + (1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 8)` may be an address of the hard disk.

Comment: You can emulate a 64-bit address space on a 32-bit machine with a lot of swap space. Probably not the answer you're looking for, but yes it's possible.

Comment: @Mysticial, how do you "emulate" a 64-bit address space when a pointer can only hold 32 bits?  RAM vs. swap is irrelevant when you're talking about virtual address space.

Comment: @Wyzard The OP says "32-bit *machine*". The OP didn't say 32-bit *program*. You could compile a 64-bit binary, run it in an emulator on 32-bit hardware using swap space.

Comment: @Mysticial, fair point, but in that case I'd contend that you're really running the program on a 64-bit machine (the one provided by the emulator).  The fact that that machine is built out of code on another computer instead of physical silicon is irrelevant.

Comment: What would you do with this 400GB of data once you created it?

Comment: What if you mapped the vector's memory to a file using the allocator? Then if the index is above XXXXX, open that file for reading and indexing? Might just require a custom container I guess but still. This idea should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't use native pointers to address 100 G of integers directly, because they will consume 400 GB of memory; some 32-bit OS may address up to 2, 3 or 4 GB of RAM, most - up to 64 GB using PAE. Still, any 32-bit program will use 32-bit pointers able to address only up to 4 GB of RAM.

All standard STL implementations (libstdc++ from gcc, libcxx from llvm+clang, stlport from russia, microsoft stl from microsoft...) use native pointers inside STL collections, and native (32-bit) size_t as collection sizes.

You may try non-standard implementaton of STL, e.g. STXXL, http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/ ([intro slides](http://dydan.rutgers.edu/Seminars/Slides/dementiev.pdf)) which reimplements some STL collections using disk (HDD) as storage. With huge (you need the 400GB at least) fast SSD you may be able to fill the vector in several days or even tens of hours, if you are lucky.

> The key features of STXXL are: Transparent support of parallel disks.
>   The library provides implementations of basic parallel disk
>   algorithms. STXXL is the only external memory algorithm library
>   supporting parallel disks. The library is able to handle problems of
>   very large size (tested to up to dozens of terabytes).

But modern versions of STXXL are not supported for 32-bit platforms; I can't say, will any older version work on 32-bit platform with so huge data... It uses some parts of STL, and if there are any size_t sized arguments, your task will fail...

Comment: Hmm, the example from pdf looks promising (10 mln of structs): `stxxl::vector<edge> Edges(10000000000ULL);`.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think that's possible.  Regardless of your allocation strategy or where the numbers are physically stored, you need enough address space to assign a distinct memory address to each integer.  Even if `sizeof(int)` were 1, you'd need 100 billion addresses available, and a 32-bit address space only has about 4 billion.

You could store the data in some other kind of container that doesn't expose the addresses of the items, and could internally use a [bank-switching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_switching) scheme to load subsets of the data as needed.  But `std::vector` exposes the memory address of the items stored within it, so every item needs to have a valid memory address at all times (regardless of whether that address is backed by RAM or swap space).

Answer (score 3):

You may try use [Boost.Interprocess](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/interprocess.html)'s `managed_mapped_file`. sample :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/interprocess/managed_mapped_file.hpp>
#include <boost/interprocess/allocators/allocator.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace ipc = boost::interprocess;

    using allocator_t = ipc::allocator<int, ipc::managed_mapped_file::segment_manager>;
    using vector_t = std::vector<int, allocator_t>;

    const char* filename = "tmp.dat";
    ipc::managed_mapped_file::size_type filesize = 4096;

    ipc::file_mapping::remove(filename);
    ipc::managed_mapped_file mfile(ipc::create_only, filename, filesize);

    vector_t* vec = mfile.construct<vector_t>("MyVector")(mfile.get_segment_manager());

    vec->resize(10, 42);
    for (int x : *vec) {
        std::cout << x << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Akira Takahashi, are you sure that this will allow std::vector to index more than 4G elements? For example, in libstdc++ from gcc-4.6 the "`size_type`" type is [hardcoded](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/libstdc++/api/a01069_source.html#l00200) as ` typedef size_t                     size_type;` which is 32-bit on standard 32-bit x86 platform.

Comment: I see, `size_type` is implementation-defined in C++(11) standard. So, We can use Boost.Container's `vector`. the `vector`'s `size_type` is `allocator_traits<Alloc>::size_type`. the `size_type` is `Alloc::size_type`. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/vector.html